# Push and Pull with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just put Bootstrap on to my website, and I have been testing it out. I have been trying to use there grid system, and I have run in to a mini problem. So on my website I have a Header, and it looks like this "Buttons 1-6 | Logo | Login". Now when my website retracts to the size of 767 pixels and smaller it still displays as above, but they each have there own row. So it looks like this "Buttons 1-6 (Top Row) | Logo (Second Row) | Login (Third Row)". Now whenever I try to do push and pull on the things, it still does not fix it. Eventually I would like it to display like this "Logo (Top Row) | Buttons 1-6 (Second Row) | Login (Third Row)" on a screen below 767 pixels. This is my HTML file:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
<div id="header" class="row">

    <div id="headerleftside" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="http://localhost/postin'/_____.html" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="headerbuttons">
                    <h1> Button 1 </h1>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="http://localhost/postin'/_____.html" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="headerbuttons">
                    <h1> Button 2 </h1>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="http://localhost/postin'/_____.html" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="headerbuttons">
                    <h1> Button 3 </h1>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="http://localhost/postin'/_____.html" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="headerbuttons">
                    <h1> Button 4 </h1>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="http://localhost/postin'/_____.html" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="headerbuttons">
                    <h1> Button 5 </h1>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="http://localhost/postin'/_____.html" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="headerbuttons">
                    <h1> Button 6 </h1>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="headertitle" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

    </div>


    <div id="headerrightside" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <form action="action.php" method="post">
            <button id="headersubmit" input type="submit"> Login </button>
            <p class="logininputboxs"> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Userame" required/> </p>
            <p class="logininputboxs"> <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/> </p>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Also please note, the above code does not have , , and other tags because this file is being used as a include() from PHP. Then the CSS file is below:

```
/*
Used Colors:
• Black - Black
• Orange - Orange
• Light Blue - #4DB8FF
• Normal Blue - #296ACC
• Normal Blue (Darker) - #2156A6
• Gray - #292D30
*/

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    position: absolute;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

#header {
    height: 15%;
    background-color: #292D30;
    position: static;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #296ACC;
    z-index: 5;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

#headerleftside {
    background-color: #292D30;
}

.headerbuttons {
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 65%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    line-height: 0%;
    font-color: #4DB8FF; /*The color is defined in the <head>, as well as the hover.*/
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

#headertitle {
    height: 120%;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2156A6;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
    background: black url("http://localhost/postin'/title.png") no-repeat center center;
}

#headertitle:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #2156A6;
    z-index: 10;
    background: black url("http://localhost/postin'/title_with_logo.png") no-repeat center center;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

#headerrightside {
    background-color: #292D30; 
}

.logininputboxs {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 0%
}

input[type=text] {
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #4DB8FF;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=password] {
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #4DB8FF;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.input_error_required {
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.input_error_unique {
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#headersubmit {
    width: 15%;
    height: 10%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #4DB8FF;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 45%;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

#sidebar {
    height: 84%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: red;
    position: static;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sidebarbuttons {
    width: 80%;
    height: 12%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 500%;
    top: 5%;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

a, u {
    text-decoration: none; !important
}
```

Then finally the actual  file is also done by Include() below by PHP:

```
<html lang="en-US">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost/postin'/favicon.ico?v=2">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }
-->
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    a:link {color: #4DB8FF;}      /* unvisited link */
    a:visited {color: #4DB8FF;}   /* visited link */
    a:hover {color: orange;}     /* mouse over link */
    a:active {color: orange;}    /* selected link */
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: This is not explained clearly but it looks like you want to put the logo first and the buttons second on small viewports. Order your html as it is on a small device, then on the first column push it 4 and on the second column pull it 4. col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 is redundant, you only need the col-sm-X variation and it will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
         LOGO
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
         BUTTONS
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4">
         OTHER STUFF
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

      </div><!-- /.row -->

  </div><!-- /.container -->
```

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/mutoju/1/edit

1. Order the html as it is on small viewports
2. Push and pull at the min-width

`.col-sm-4` is the same as `.col-md-4` and `.col-lg-4`. It's 33.3333% of the parent. From the `.col-sm-` min-width (768px by default) till whenever, that will be the size. So you don't need to use `.col-md-4` or `.col-lg-4`, it's redundant.